# Space between words in matplotlib plot axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to print the foll. as x-axis label in matplotlib:

```
r'$Area (km^{2})$'
```

However, when I pass it along to `plt.ylabel(r'$Area (km^{2})$')`, the resulting plot does not have a space between `Area` and `(km^{2})`. How do I introduce a space between them?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add `\` before space character:

```
`r'$Area\ (km^{2})$'`
```

Or move `Area` (with space) out of `$...$` expression:

```
r'Area $(km^{2})$'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various way to introduce some space between characters. Depending on the size of the gap you want, you can use: "\", "\,", "\;", "\quad", "\qquad"

Here, you'll find a nice overview: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode